# uwsgi ssl issue error unavailable modifier requested: 22

Tags: python, uwsgi

I am unable to get SSL working with uwsgi and getting the following error in logs when request is sent. Based on the research, i am understanding its because of some missing plugin but not sure which one is that.
--unavailable modifier requested: 22--

From the postman when i tried i am getting the following error shown in post man:
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Following is the config:

```
[uwsgi]
 master = True
 https =  =0,signals.crt,signals.key,HIGH
 socket=0.0.0.0:5000
 chdir = /somepath
 wsgi-file = /somepath
 processes = 4
 threads = 2
 stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing libs openssl-devel  and openssl resolved the issue. thank you.